# Do apps built with AppMaker scale?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is this a robust app build & deploy tool that can be used to deploy apps to the public, with large numbers of users without failing or performance degradation?
Has anyone published an app that has 10,000's of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At this App Maker targets enterprise market and doesn't allow to create publicly available apps.
2. App Maker uses App Script as runtime and it has some quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Thanks for your answer.